# Partial fraction on $\frac{2\cos^2(x)-1}{a^2-2a\cos(x)+1}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, partial-fractions

$$\frac{2\cos^2(x)-1}{a^2-2a\cos(x)+1}$$ I've seen this thing on an integral on this site and this is doable with partial decomposition (also checked with Wolfram), but my question is: how? I tried factoring since what I've learned is that you have to have factors in the denominator to do the: $$\frac{A}{\text{denominator 1}}+\frac{B}{\text{denominator 2}}$$, etc. But I don't know if having a $(\sqrt{1+a^2}+\sqrt{2a\cos(x)})(\sqrt{1+a^2}-\sqrt{2a\cos(x)})$ would help to do partial decomposition? Also tried long division since the degree is higher than in the denominator but didn't work either. Any hints?

Comment: What is the variable on which you want to integrate? $x$ or $a$? If you want to perform partial decomposition it should be $a$ as partial decomposition deals with rational fractions.

Comment: @Acyex: Are you looking for $$ \dfrac{2\cos^2(x)-1}{a^2-2a\cos(x)+1} = \dfrac{-a^4-1}{2 a^2 \left(-a^2+2 a \cos (x)-1\right)}-\dfrac{a^2+1}{2 a^2}-\dfrac{\cos (x)}{a}$$

Comment: yes i am @Moo, that's the one

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net oh really? never thought of that, then I treat cos(x) as a constant or what? But the integral was with respect to x, but that's out of my point regardless, I'm only interested in the partial fraction decomposition and I'm still looking for one answer :(

Answer (score 2):

*I suppose that you are integrating for $x$.*

The first thing I would do is to use the tangent half-angle substitution $x=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$$

$$\int\frac{2\cos^2(x)-1}{a^2-2a\cos(x)+1}\,dx=\int\frac{2 \left(t^4-6 t^2+1\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2 \left((a+1)^2
   t^2+(a-1)^2\right)}\,dt$$ Now
$$\frac{2 \left(t^4-6 t^2+1\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2 \left((a+1)^2
   t^2+(a-1)^2\right)}=$$ $$-\frac{(a-1)^2}{a^2 \left(t^2+1\right)}-\frac{4}{a \left(t^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{a^4+1}{a^2 \left((a+1)^2 t^2+(a-1)^2\right)}$$

Comment: The numerator is a poly of degree 2 in $\cos x$, while the denominator is linear in $\cos x$ - as in the comments above, probably easier to do the division first before other substitutions...

Comment: You can also split the numerators and possibly the factored denominator of $\frac{a^4+1}{a^2(…)}$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash. There are so many things we could do ! Cheers ;-). By the way, congratulations for your questions !

Comment: @peterag. There are so many things we could do ! Cheers ;-).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What do you mean by “congratulations”? I see, it may be possible to do partial fractions on the factored denominators. You can also leave the answer as is for simplicity.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer that doesn't involve unintuitive substitutions, since what I asked was the partial fraction decomposition, not the integral, in spite of so, i appreciate your post!